# Visual Studio - Cmake Project - Add NetCDF

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, netcdf

I have a project that I was able to compile in Linux, but was also hoping to compile in a windows environment, namely, visual studio.

I installed netcdf, but when I build using cmake, I get this error:

```
Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE) 
1> -- Checking for one of the modules 'netcdf'
1> CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.11/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:641 (message):
1>   None of the required 'netcdf' found
```

Any idea how to get Visual studio to find the netcdf package?

Comment: You'll probably need to specify a path when you configure cmake.. but that's just a guess.

Comment: @Ben Could you post *some* of your CMakeLists.txt? The part where you invoke `find_package`?

Answer (score 1):

To get you started, take a look at the variable [`PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.13/module/FindPkgConfig.html#variable:PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE). This variable will add that search path the sub-call of `find_program`, which CMake runs. You can set that varible in your CMakeLists.txt file, right before your call to `FindPkgConfig`.

For some more complete error checking,  you should try to always look into the corresponding "FOUND" or "NOTFOUND" property of the CMake variable(s):

```
if(PKG_CONFIG_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "PKG_CONFIG_FOUND!")
else()
    message(WARNING "PKG_CONFIG_FOUND was false!")
endif()
```