# Unresolved External Symbols When Using NetCDF (Installed via vcpkg) with CMake in a C++ Project on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cmake, netcdf

*The question has been updated sinces its original posting. I have kept everything for context and information for people in the future, but the latest information and issues are at the bottom.*

I have found somewhat [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52977344/visual-studio-cmake-project-add-netcdf) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61232966/netcdf-library-linkage-on-windows-with-cmake) posted previously about related subjects, but none of them seemed to have a clear, concise resolution for what exactly I'm doing. I'm hoping that by asking this question, I can get an answer and there will also be a more clear answer available on the internet for future people with similar troubles.

I am trying to create a simple example C++ code using NetCDF in Visual Studio 2019 with CMake as the build system. I installed NetCDF using `vcpkg`, specifically the command

`vcpkg install netcdf-cxx:x64-windows`

which installed all prerequisite packages and netcdf-cxx:x64-windows to `C:\Program Files\vcpkg\packages`.

In the project itself, I have two main files: `main.cpp` and `CMakeLists.txt`. The directory structure is as follows:

```
- C:\
     - Users\
          - Owner\
               - Education and Research\
                    - Personal Projects\
                         - learning_coding\
                              - C++\
                                   - cmake_netcdf\
                                        - CMakeLists.txt
                                        - main.cpp
```

The file `main.cpp` is

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <netcdf>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello world!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

while `CMakeLists.txt` is

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17)

project(cmake_netcdf)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable(cmake_netcdf main.cpp)

# Find and include the netcdf package
find_package(netcdf CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(cmake_netcdf
                      PRIVATE netcdf
                     )
```

Visual Studio can successfully refresh C++ IntelliSense information,

```
1> CMake generation started for configuration: 'x64-Debug'.
1> Found and using vcpkg toolchain file (C:/Program Files/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake).
1> The toolchain file has changed (CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE).
1> Command line: "cmd.exe" /c ""C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Ninja"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\out\install\x64-Debug" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"  -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM="C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\CMAKE\Ninja\ninja.exe" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE="C:/Program Files/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" "C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug
1> [CMake] -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29111.0
1> [CMake] -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.27.29111.0
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
1> [CMake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.27.29110/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - works
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
1> [CMake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
1> [CMake] -- Found ZLIB: optimized;C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found version "1.2.11") 
1> [CMake] -- Found ZLIB: optimized;C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/zlib.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/zlibd.lib (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1") 
1> [CMake] -- Configuring done
1> [CMake] -- Generating done
1> [CMake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Owner/Education and Research/Personal Projects/learning_coding/C++/cmake_netcdf/build/x64-Debug
1> Extracted CMake variables.
1> Extracted source files and headers.
1> Extracted code model.
1> Extracted includes paths.
1> CMake generation finished.
```

but the project fails to build and gives the error messages `cannot open source file "netcdf"` and `Cannot open include file: 'netcdf': No such file or directory`. How can I fix this error?

EDIT 1: Following up on the comments:

1. "Can you check in the Solution Properties->Include Directories whether the path to the netcdf include is set?" – user3389943

This code isn't saved as a solution, but you did prompt me to look at the CMake variables. The directory variable for netcdf is `netcdf_DIR = C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/netcdf-c`, which looks like

```
- C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/netcdf-c/
     - copyright
     - netCDFConfig.cmake
     - netCDFConfigVersion.cmake
     - netCDFTargets.cmake
     - netCDFTargets-debug.cmake
     - netCDFTargets-release.cmake
     - usage
     - vcpkg_abi_info.txt
```

There is not variable for `netcdf_INCLUDES` or anything of that sort. Is it an issue that it's looking at netcdf-c for a C++ program? How do I get CMake to look for the proper include directories?

2. "There is no header named netcdf in the NetCDF package. It should read #include "netcdf.h"." – vre

Making that change does not fix the error, it gives the same error replacing `'netcdf'` with `"netcdf.h"`. I think the proper `include` is `netcdf`, unless the [tutorials](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/examples/programs/) are out-of-date.

EDIT 2: Following up on the comments:

1. ""I think the proper include is netcdf": The include file is definitely named netcdf.h. Your find_package call should try to find netCDF, case matters here. In the netCDFTargets-debug.cmake there is a target defined with add_library(<> IMPORTED ...). Use this target name for your target_link_libraries command." – vre

Thank you for telling me about this file! The file `netCDFTargets-debug.cmake` reads

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file for configuration "DEBUG".
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Import target "netCDF::netcdf" for configuration "DEBUG"
set_property(TARGET netCDF::netcdf APPEND PROPERTY IMPORTED_CONFIGURATIONS DEBUG)
set_target_properties(netCDF::netcdf PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_IMPLIB_DEBUG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/debug/lib/netcdf.lib"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_DEBUG "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/debug/bin/netcdf.dll"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS netCDF::netcdf )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_netCDF::netcdf "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/debug/lib/netcdf.lib" "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/debug/bin/netcdf.dll" )

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
```

So I changed my `CMakeLists.txt` to

```
# Unit test for building a program with netCDF using CMake in visual studio.

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.17)

project(cmake_netcdf)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable(cmake_netcdf main.cpp)

# Find and include the netcdf package
find_package(netCDF CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(cmake_netcdf
                      PRIVATE netCDF::netcdf
                     )
```

and now `main.cpp` builds! It builds using both `#include <netcdf>` and `#include "netcdf.h"`.

From here, I decided to change `main.cpp` to an example file on NCAR's website, so `main.cpp` now is

```
/* This is part of the netCDF package.
   Copyright 2006 University Corporation for Atmospheric Research/Unidata.
   See COPYRIGHT file for conditions of use.

   This is a very simple example which writes a 2D array of
   sample data. To handle this in netCDF we create two shared
   dimensions, "x" and "y", and a netCDF variable, called "data".

   This example is part of the netCDF tutorial:
   http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-tutorial

   Full documentation of the netCDF C++ API can be found at:
   http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/netcdf-cxx

   $Id: simple_xy_wr.cpp,v 1.5 2010/02/11 22:36:43 russ Exp $
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <netcdf>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
using namespace netCDF;
using namespace netCDF::exceptions;

// We are writing 2D data, a 6 x 12 grid. 
static const int NX = 6;
static const int NY = 12;

// Return this in event of a problem.
static const int NC_ERR = 2;



int main()
{
    // This is the data array we will write. It will just be filled
    // with a progression of numbers for this example.
    int dataOut[NX][NY];

    // Create some pretend data. If this wasn't an example program, we
    // would have some real data to write, for example, model output.
    for (int i = 0; i < NX; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < NY; j++)
            dataOut[i][j] = i * NY + j;

    // The default behavior of the C++ API is to throw an exception i
    // an error occurs. A try catch block is necessary.

    try
    {
        // Create the file. The Replace parameter tells netCDF to overwrite
        // this file, if it already exists.
        NcFile dataFile("simple_xy.nc", NcFile::replace);
        
        // Create netCDF dimensions
        NcDim xDim = dataFile.addDim("x", NX);
        NcDim yDim = dataFile.addDim("y", NY);
        
        // Define the variable. The type of the variable in this case is
        // ncInt (32-bit integer).
        vector<NcDim> dims;
        dims.push_back(xDim);
        dims.push_back(yDim);
        NcVar data = dataFile.addVar("data", ncInt, dims);

        // Write the data to the file. Although netCDF supports
        // reading and writing subsets of data, in this case we write all
        // the data in one operation.
        data.putVar(dataOut);

        // The file will be automatically close when the NcFile object goes
        // out of scope. This frees up any internal netCDF resources
        // associated with the file, and flushes any buffers.
        
        //cout << "*** SUCCESS writing example file simple_xy.nc!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    catch (NcException& e)
    {
        e.what();
        return NC_ERR;
    }

}
```

When trying to build this example file, I get a bunch of linker errors

```
>------ Build All started: Project: cmake_netcdf, Configuration: x64-Debug ------
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir\main.cpp.obj
  [2/2] Linking CXX executable cmake_netcdf.exe
  FAILED: cmake_netcdf.exe 
  cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100183~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1427~1.291\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir\main.cpp.obj  /out:cmake_netcdf.exe /implib:cmake_netcdf.lib /pdb:cmake_netcdf.pdb /version:0.0  /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  "C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\netcdf.lib"  "C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\hdf5_hl_D.lib"  "C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\hdf5_D.lib"  "C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\libcurl-d.lib"  "C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\zlibd.lib"  wldap32.lib  winmm.lib  ws2_32.lib  advapi32.lib  crypt32.lib  advapi32.lib  crypt32.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cmd.exe /C "cd /D "C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug" && powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy Bypass -file "C:/Program Files/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/msbuild/applocal.ps1" -targetBinary "C:/Users/Owner/Education and Research/Personal Projects/learning_coding/C++/cmake_netcdf/build/x64-Debug/cmake_netcdf.exe" -installedDir "C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/bin" -OutVariable out""
  LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1427~1.291\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir\main.cpp.obj /out:cmake_netcdf.exe /implib:cmake_netcdf.lib /pdb:cmake_netcdf.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\netcdf.lib C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\hdf5_hl_D.lib C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\hdf5_D.lib C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\libcurl-d.lib C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\debug\lib\zlibd.lib wldap32.lib winmm.lib ws2_32.lib advapi32.lib crypt32.lib advapi32.lib crypt32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1120) with the following output:
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl netCDF::NcDim::NcDim(class netCDF::NcDim const &)" (??0NcDim@netCDF@@QEAA@AEBV01@@Z) referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl std::_Default_allocator_traits<class std::allocator<class netCDF::NcDim> >::construct<class netCDF::NcDim,class netCDF::NcDim &>(class std::allocator<class netCDF::NcDim> &,class netCDF::NcDim * const,class netCDF::NcDim &)" (??$construct@VNcDim@netCDF@@AEAV12@@?$_Default_allocator_traits@V?$allocator@VNcDim@netCDF@@@std@@@std@@SAXAEAV?$allocator@VNcDim@netCDF@@@1@QEAVNcDim@netCDF@@AEAV34@@Z)
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class netCDF::NcVar __cdecl netCDF::NcGroup::addVar(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,class netCDF::NcType const &,class std::vector<class netCDF::NcDim,class std::allocator<class netCDF::NcDim> > const &)const " (?addVar@NcGroup@netCDF@@QEBA?AVNcVar@2@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBVNcType@2@AEBV?$vector@VNcDim@netCDF@@V?$allocator@VNcDim@netCDF@@@std@@@5@@Z) referenced in function main
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class netCDF::NcDim __cdecl netCDF::NcGroup::addDim(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned __int64)const " (?addDim@NcGroup@netCDF@@QEBA?AVNcDim@2@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@_K@Z) referenced in function main
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl netCDF::NcFile::NcFile(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,enum netCDF::NcFile::FileMode)" (??0NcFile@netCDF@@QEAA@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4FileMode@01@@Z) referenced in function main
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl netCDF::NcFile::~NcFile(void)" (??1NcFile@netCDF@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl netCDF::NcVar::putVar(void const *)const " (?putVar@NcVar@netCDF@@QEBAXPEBX@Z) referenced in function main
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug\main.cpp.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class netCDF::NcInt netCDF::ncInt" (?ncInt@netCDF@@3VNcInt@1@A)
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\build\x64-Debug\cmake_netcdf.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Build All failed.
```

I tried replacing `#include <netcdf>` with `#include "netcdf.h"` but I got even more errors:

```
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir\main.cpp.obj
  FAILED: CMakeFiles/cmake_netcdf.dir/main.cpp.obj 
  C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~1\2019\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1427~1.291\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP -DDEBUG -DH5_BUILT_AS_DYNAMIC_LIB -I"C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include" /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /GR /EHsc /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -MDd /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir\main.cpp.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmake_netcdf.dir\ /FS -c ..\..\main.cpp
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(22): error C2871: 'netCDF': a namespace with this name does not exist
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(23): error C2653: 'netCDF': is not a class or namespace name
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(23): error C2871: 'exceptions': a namespace with this name does not exist
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(53): error C2065: 'NcFile': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(53): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'dataFile'
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(53): error C2653: 'NcFile': is not a class or namespace name
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(53): error C2065: 'replace': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(53): error C3861: 'dataFile': identifier not found
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(56): error C2065: 'NcDim': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(56): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'xDim'
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(56): error C2065: 'xDim': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(56): error C2065: 'dataFile': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(57): error C2065: 'NcDim': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(57): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'yDim'
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(57): error C2065: 'yDim': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(57): error C2065: 'dataFile': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(61): error C2065: 'NcDim': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(61): error C2923: 'std::vector': 'NcDim' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(61): error C2976: 'std::vector': too few template arguments
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\vector(413): note: see declaration of 'std::vector'
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(61): error C2133: 'dims': unknown size
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(61): error C2512: 'std::vector': no appropriate default constructor available
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\vector(413): note: see declaration of 'std::vector'
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(62): error C2065: 'xDim': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(63): error C2065: 'yDim': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(64): error C2065: 'NcVar': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(64): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'data'
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(64): error C2065: 'dataFile': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(64): error C2065: 'ncInt': undeclared identifier
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(78): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'NcException'
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(78): error C2310: catch handlers must specify one type
C:\Users\Owner\Education and Research\Personal Projects\learning_coding\C++\cmake_netcdf\main.cpp(80): error C2065: 'e': undeclared identifier
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Build All failed.
```

Any insight on these new issues? A Google search brought me to [this page](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/support/help/MailArchives/netcdf/msg13602.html) which suggests that CMake is linking against a 32-bit version of the library (whereas my system is 64 bit), but I only have the 64-bit version of the library installed.

Also, with regards to `#include <netcdf>` versus `#include "netcdf.h"`, I have both files in `C:\Program Files\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include` (along with a bunch of header files related to HDF5 and stuff). It seems like `<netcdf>` is the whole thing while `netcdf.h` is just part of it?

2. "netcdf_DIR is where find_package searches for the headers and libraries. Can you cross check the target name as @vre mentioned?" – user3389943

I certainly can! `netcdf_DIR` is `C:/Program Files/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/netcdf-c`, which I mentioned the contents of in Edit 1.

The `netCDFTargets.cmake` file has the line `add_library(netCDF::netcdf SHARED IMPORTED)`, which I used for the newest version of the `target_link_libraries` command.

EDIT 3: Following up on the comments:

1. "So what other targets are defined in netCDFTargets.cmake" – user3389943

I'm not entirely sure how to parse `netCDFTargets.cmake`, so here are the contents:

```
# Generated by CMake

if("${CMAKE_MAJOR_VERSION}.${CMAKE_MINOR_VERSION}" LESS 2.5)
   message(FATAL_ERROR "CMake >= 2.6.0 required")
endif()
cmake_policy(PUSH)
cmake_policy(VERSION 2.6)
#----------------------------------------------------------------
# Generated CMake target import file.
#----------------------------------------------------------------

# Commands may need to know the format version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION 1)

# Protect against multiple inclusion, which would fail when already imported targets are added once more.
set(_targetsDefined)
set(_targetsNotDefined)
set(_expectedTargets)
foreach(_expectedTarget netCDF::netcdf)
  list(APPEND _expectedTargets ${_expectedTarget})
  if(NOT TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsNotDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
  if(TARGET ${_expectedTarget})
    list(APPEND _targetsDefined ${_expectedTarget})
  endif()
endforeach()
if("${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "${_expectedTargets}")
  unset(_targetsDefined)
  unset(_targetsNotDefined)
  unset(_expectedTargets)
  set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
  cmake_policy(POP)
  return()
endif()
if(NOT "${_targetsDefined}" STREQUAL "")
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined.\nTargets Defined: ${_targetsDefined}\nTargets not yet defined: ${_targetsNotDefined}\n")
endif()
unset(_targetsDefined)
unset(_targetsNotDefined)
unset(_expectedTargets)


# Compute the installation prefix relative to this file.
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
get_filename_component(_IMPORT_PREFIX "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}" PATH)
if(_IMPORT_PREFIX STREQUAL "/")
  set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "")
endif()

# Create imported target netCDF::netcdf
add_library(netCDF::netcdf SHARED IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(netCDF::netcdf PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include;${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "ZLIB::ZLIB;hdf5::hdf5-shared;hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared;CURL::libcurl"
)

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "This file relies on consumers using CMake 2.8.12 or greater.")
endif()

# Load information for each installed configuration.
get_filename_component(_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}" PATH)
file(GLOB CONFIG_FILES "${_DIR}/netCDFTargets-*.cmake")
foreach(f ${CONFIG_FILES})
  include(${f})
endforeach()

# Cleanup temporary variables.
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX)

# Loop over all imported files and verify that they actually exist
foreach(target ${_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS} )
  foreach(file ${_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target}} )
    if(NOT EXISTS "${file}" )
      message(FATAL_ERROR "The imported target \"${target}\" references the file
   \"${file}\"
but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:
* The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.
* An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.
* The installation package was faulty and contained
   \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_FILE}\"
but not all the files it references.
")
    endif()
  endforeach()
  unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_${target})
endforeach()
unset(_IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS)

# This file does not depend on other imported targets which have
# been exported from the same project but in a separate export set.

# Commands beyond this point should not need to know the version.
set(CMAKE_IMPORT_FILE_VERSION)
cmake_policy(POP)
```

Does that help?

Comment: Can you check in the Solution Properties->Include Directories whether the path to the netcdf include is set?

Comment: There is no header named `netcdf` in the NetCDF package. It should read `#include "netcdf.h"`

Comment: @user3389943 Addressed your comment in the first edit, thanks for the help!

Comment: @vre Addressed your comment in the first edit, thanks for the help!

Comment: *"I think the proper include is netcdf"*: The include file is definitely named `netcdf.h`. Your `find_package` call should try to find `netCDF`, case matters here. In the `netCDFTargets-debug.cmake` there is a target defined with `add_library(<> IMPORTED ...)`. Use this target name for your `target_link_libraries` command.

Comment: netcdf_DIR  is where find_package searches for the headers and libraries. Can you cross check the target name as @vre mentioned?

Comment: @vre Addressed your comment in the second edit, thanks for the help!

Comment: @user3389943 Addressed your comment in the second edit, thanks for the help!

Comment: So what other targets are defined in netCDFTargets.cmake

Comment: @user3389943 Addressed your comment in the third edit, thanks for the help!

Comment: I do not see any more targets. The error looks like you missed some libraries that should be linked to your program. You have already linked netcdf. So I am not sure what did you miss .

Comment: @user3389943 I'm not sure what I missed either, but I do sincerely appreciate the time and effort you put into helping me. I will continue to work on this, and hopefully I'll be able to resolve it. I will report back if/when I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution! It most certainly is not a perfect solution, but it is a solution.

Unfortunately, I was not able to get it to work on Visual Studio with Windows. I will probably try again at some point, but I think the version of `netCDF-cxx4` is out of date on `vcpkg` or something. I am currently away from my primary work station, so I will have to try again on there to see if I can get a solution in Visual Studio. Anyway, here's what I did that seemed to work:

1. I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.1 via the [Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). I'm not sure if this will work for older or newer versions of Ubuntu, but I assume that it will. I also am using the Windows Terminal that they mention on that page and set up my colors with the `vimrc` example file found [here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Example_vimrc).

This changes how your file system works a bit by adding two layers above `C:\`, which are `/mnt/`. You can navigate to your files on Windows by going to `/mnt/c/Users/` and to the Ubuntu subsystem by going to `/`. I named my Ubuntu account `usr`, so the 'desktop' Ubuntu files are kept in `/home/usr`. For all of the subsequent steps, I am using the Ubuntu terminal window in the Windows Terminal application.

There was also an issue with installing `zlib` via `vcpkg` after enabling WSL, but I don't know how to resolve it nor have I found a solution anywhere.

2. I downloaded a C++ compiler by running `sudo apt install build-essential`, and installed CMake and netCDF-C via `sudo apt install cmake libnetcdf-dev`.
3. I installed `netCDF-cxx4` by cloning their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf-cxx4) to my home directory `/home/usr` and using the commands

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
ctest
sudo make install
```

If you don't have that `sudo` there, you'll get a permissions error.

4. I found the `netCDFCxxConfig.cmake` file in the directory `/usr/local/lib/cmake/netcdf` and made some changes to the `CMakeLists.txt` file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

# Set project name and version
project(cmake_netcdfcxx4)

# Find the netcdf-cxx4 library
list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/usr/local/lib/cmake/netCDF")
find_package(netCDFCxx REQUIRED)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable(cmake_netcdfcxx4 main.cpp)

# Link the netcdf-cxx4 library to the executable
target_link_libraries(cmake_netcdfcxx4
                      PRIVATE
                         netCDF::netcdf-cxx4
                     )
```

to add this directory to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable. I'm still looking into how to add the directory `/usr/local/lib/cmake/` to the CMake search path automatically so the user doesn't have to edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file to compile this properly, so I guess this will require some updating.

I hope this helps people in the future!